# How to search cases by CompanyId in Netsuite Suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I can able to search the case by company name

```
var mySearch = search.create({
      type: search.Type.SUPPORT_CASE,
       columns: [{
          name: 'title'
      }, {
          name: 'company'
      }],
      filters: [{
          name: 'company',
          operator: 'is',
          values: 'Test'
      }]
  });
  return mySearch.run({
    ld: mySearch.id
  }).getRange({
      start: 0,
      end: 1000
  });
```

But I am not able to search case by company id.
companyId is 115

Below are not working

i)

```
filters: [{
          name: 'company',
          operator: 'is',
          values: 115
      }]
```

ii)

```
filters: [{
          name: 'companyid',
          operator: 'is',
          values: 115
      }]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Case schema](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_2/script/record/supportcase.html) `company` is a Text filter, meaning you would have to provide it with the precise Name of the company, not the internal ID.

Instead you may want to use the `customer.internalid` joined filter to provide the internal ID. Also, Internal ID fields are nearly always Select fields, meaning they do not accept the `is` operator, but instead require the `anyof` or `noneof` operator.

You can find the valid operators by field type on the Help page titled `Search Operators`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation eric. 
But ["company.internalid","is","115"] is working

Comment: @Prabhu Are you sure it is returning the right values with "IS" : sometimes the search doesn't give an error, but it will give wrong results if not using the right operator. In this case, the right operator is "ANYOF".

Comment: Yes. I am sure. It is working with "is". I tested with contact & supportcase. Both returned exact results

Answer (score 2):

First, you can try this :

```
var supportcaseSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "supportcase",
   filters:
   [
      ["company.internalid","anyof","100"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({
         name: "casenumber",
         sort: search.Sort.ASC
      }),
      "title",
      "company",
      "contact",
      "stage",
      "status",
      "profile",
      "startdate",
      "createddate",
      "category",
      "assigned",
      "priority"
   ]
});
```

Second : how did I get this ? The answer is hint that will make your life easier :

1. Install the "NetSuite Saved Search Code Export" chrome plugin.
2. In Netsuite UI, create your saved search (it is always easier that doing it in code).
3. After saving the search, open it again for edition.
4. At the top right corner (near list, search menu in the netsuite page), you will see a link "Export as script" : click on it and you will get your code ;)

If you can not install the chrome plugin :

1. In Netsuite UI, create your saved search (it is always easier that doing it in code).
2. In your code, load your saved search
3. Add a log.debug to show the `[loadedesearchVar].filters`
4. You can then copy what you will see in the log to use it as your search filters.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for giving more detail Assem